# What are the disadvantages of contained database in ms sql 2017

Tags: contained-database

What are the disadvantages of contained database in Microsoft SQL Server 2017? I want to introduce contained database in my organization. I would like to know what limitations exist. Reasons why I should not implement it would be useful too.

Comment: That is a pretty broad question; it would depend on all sorts of things, such as size of your company, type of data, etc.

Comment: I think this question could essentially be "what limitations exist?" which would make it a more answerable question. This would answer a similar question of when contained databases are not a solution. @Azirila, if that addresses your question, you might try editing your question to take that alternate approach

Comment: There are several limitations listed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#Limitations